# SELECT e INSERT una variable en el mismo procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente problema: Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL cen el cual busco guardar el resultado de un SELECT en una variable. Luego, en el mismo procedimiento, quiero insertar la variable en una tabla mediante un INSERT. Sin embargo, cuando llamo mi procedimiento y consulto la tabla, el campo donde deberia venir el valor de la variable insertada tiene null.
Mi ps es el siguiente:

```
REATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_product_quantity_cart`(cartId int, quant int, productId int)
BEGIN
declare price_row int;

select  price*quantity into price_row from product inner join test_product_quantity_cart 
on product.id_product=test_product_quantity_cart.id_product
 where id_cart=cartId and test_product_quantity_cart.id_product=productId;
 
insert into test_product_quantity_cart(id_cart,quantity,id_product,price_product)  values(cartId,quant,productId,price_row);
END
```

Al llamar este ps:

```
 call insert_product_quantity_cart(4,3,4)
```

Obtengo la siguiente fila:
4   3   4   null
Siendo null el campo de la columna price_product
Asimismo, decidi correr mi primer SELECT en un query separado para asegurarme de que regrese el valor esperado, y en efecto el SELECT funciona
Este es el primer select statment del procedimiento:

```
select  price*quantity as total from product inner join test_product_quantity_cart 
on product.id_product=test_product_quantity_cart.id_product
 where id_cart=4 and test_product_quantity_cart.id_product=4;
```

El  resultado de este statement es
27.
Lo anterior porque el producto con id_producto=4 tiene un precio de 9, y quantity =3.

Comment: ¿Cuántos elementos te devuelve el select que usas para sacar el price_row?

Comment: solamenete uno. Estoy multiplicando una columna precio unitario con una columna cantidad. Si precio unitario es por ejemplo: jabones=5 pesos y cantidad es 2, price_row es 10.

Comment: Chequea la respuesta planteada.

Answer (score 2):

**Puedes optar por lo siguiente.**

1. Cambiar el `declare price_row int;` por `@price_row`, estas variables son variables de tipificación libre que pueden inicializarse en algún momento de una sesión y mantener su valor hasta el final de la misma.
2. Delimita tu query de tal forma que le indiques que solo va a retornar un solo valor y no una lista de valores. Por ejemplo con un `LIMIT 1`.

Entonces con los puntos antes mencionados queda de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_product_quantity_cart`(cartId int, quant int, productId int)
BEGIN
#declare price_row int;
set @price_row = (select price_row from product 
                  inner join test_product_quantity_cart 
                  on product.id_product=test_product_quantity_cart.id_product
                  where id_cart=cartId and test_product_quantity_cart.id_product=productId
                  limit 1);

insert into test_product_quantity_cart(id_cart, quantity, id_product, price_product)  values(cartId,quant, productId, @price_row);
END
```

Comment: Aún modificando el codigo de esta manera sigo obteniendo null en el campo price_product.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y presenta el select que haces para probar y su resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Un query mas sencillo en el SELECT y multiplicando precio por cantidad en el INSERT se obtiene la respuesta esperada.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_product_quantity_cart`(cartId int, quant int, productId int)
BEGIN


set @price_row= (select  price from product where id_product=productId);
 
insert into test_product_quantity_cart(id_cart,quantity,id_product,price_product)  values(cartId,quant,productId,@price_row*quantity);
END
```